# JQuery/Ajax/Class: removeClass() then addClass() is not working as intended inside ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, class, button

I have two ajax functions that is using the same button. My intention is in my `save_button` class, `add_group` is there by default but what I want to do is when my Edit button is clicked, `add_group` will be removed and be replaced by `update_group` so that a different ajax function is used

**Save Button:**

```
<button type="submit" class="save_button add_group">Save</button>
```

**Edit Button:**

```
<button type="button" class="edit_group">Edit</button>
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_group', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
 (additional content) });

$(document).on('click', '.update_group', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  (additional content )});
```

What I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_group', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $(".save_button").removeClass("add_group").addClass("update_group"); });
```

This function seems to not work, the save button does not trigger the add or update if I use this function. asking for any advice on how to fix this.

(Goal: trigger `removeClass` and `addClass` when edit_button is clicked)

Comment: What do you mean by _"seems to not work"_?

Comment: Seems to work fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/jdr9f05t/

Comment: Without a description of the problem, this question is likely to be closed.  Is your code not working, if so what happens, any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', //....
```

Is really a poor choice for capturing events.  This requires the event to bubble up through every parent element to the document.  It's slow and can cause you massive headaches if you have any parent elements that capture elements (because they may cancel the bubbling of the event as well).  I'll demonstrate below a better solution.

Per the [JQuery Documentation `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest, innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create consistent cross-browser behavior.

Changing what a button does via class/bindings is also a poor choice because it's much harder to keep track of state on the object itself when it's not the container of what is happening.

I would highly recommend reading [Philip Walton's (Engineer @ Google) - Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

```js
$(".js-edit-button").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.form')
    .removeClass('is-add')
    .addClass('is-update');
});
 
$(".js-save-button").on('click', function(e) {
  var $lastAcion = $(this).closest('.form')
    .find('.form-save-last-action-type');

  if ($(this).closest('.form').is('.is-add')) {
    $lastAcion.text('Add');
  }

  if ($(this).closest('.form').is('.is-update')) {
    $lastAcion.text('Update');
  }
});
```

```css
.form.is-add .is-update {
  display: none;
}

.form.is-update .is-add {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form is-add">
  <div class="is-add">Form is in Add Mode</div>
  <div class="is-update">Form is in Update Mode</div>
  
  <button type="button" class="js-save-button">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="js-edit-button">Edit</button>
  <div class="form-save-last-action-type">None</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah poor choice of words.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: your answer is a great read, thanks for the detailed feedback, will definitely remember this advice